# How to plot a map with time-slider and zoom on a city with plotly in python

Tags: python, plotly, maps

I want to create an interactive map that shows the evolution of a variable (number of bikes) on different points of a city.

Why not by using plotly.

I would like to do something like this : https://amaral.northwestern.edu/blog/step-step-how-plot-map-slider-represent-time-evolu with a slider.

However, I don't achieve to reproduce it with focusing on a city, I can't choose a scope more precise than "europe".

Do you know how to do it with a zoom ?

Comment: Can you include any code you've written so far?

Comment: Hi Elise, it will be great if you can provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- you have not provided any code or sample data.  Hence have used this http://api.citybik.es/v2/ https://github.com/eskerda/pybikes project to source some bike data
- data is just latest,  so build up data in a **pickle** file for evolution
- simple case of using **Plotly Express** and `animation_frame` argument

#### data sources

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path
import plotly.express as px

# avalaible data sources...
pd.json_normalize(
    requests.get("http://api.citybik.es/v2/networks").json()["networks"]
).loc[lambda d: d["location.city"].eq("London")]
```

#### bike stand sourcing and plotting

```
df = pd.json_normalize(
    requests.get("http://api.citybik.es/v2/networks/santander-cycles").json()[
        "network"
    ]["stations"]
)

# build up some data over time
df["timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df["timestamp"]).round("15min")
f = Path.cwd().joinpath("bikes.pickle")
if not f.exists():
    df.to_pickle(f)
else:
    df = pd.concat([pd.read_pickle(f), df])
    df = df.groupby(["timestamp","id"], as_index=False).first()
    df.to_pickle(f)

# now just plot it on a map with evolution by time
df["ts_str"] = df["timestamp"].dt.strftime("%d-%b %H:%M")
px.scatter_mapbox(
    df,
    lat="latitude",
    lon="longitude",
    size="free_bikes",
    hover_data=["name"],
    animation_frame="ts_str",
).update_layout(
    mapbox={"style": "carto-positron", "zoom":11}, margin={"l": 0, "r": 0, "t": 0, "b": 0}
)
```

[image]